# Eager fetching - find vs JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a one-to-one relationship between two entities - Student and Address.

```
//Student

@OneToOne(fetch = EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private Address address;
```

Invoking `entityManager.find(Student.class, 1)` results in ADDRESS eagerly fetched as expected:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        student0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        student0_.address_id as address_7_4_0_,
        student0_.crt_ts as crt_ts2_4_0_,
        student0_.email as email3_4_0_,
        student0_.first_name as first_na4_4_0_,
        student0_.last_name as last_nam5_4_0_,
        student0_.upd_ts as upd_ts6_4_0_,
        address1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        address1_.city as city2_1_1_,
        address1_.state as state3_1_1_,
        address1_.street as street4_1_1_,
        address1_.zip as zip5_1_1_ 
    from
        t_student student0_ 
    left outer join
        t_address address1_ 
            on student0_.address_id=address1_.id 
    where
        student0_.id=1
```

But, invoking

```
String query = "select s from Student s where s.id=1";
return entityManager.createQuery(query, Student.class).getSingleResult();
```

does not trigger eager fetching of ADDRESS:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        student0_.id as id1_4_,
        student0_.address_id as address_7_4_,
        student0_.crt_ts as crt_ts2_4_,
        student0_.email as email3_4_,
        student0_.first_name as first_na4_4_,
        student0_.last_name as last_nam5_4_,
        student0_.upd_ts as upd_ts6_4_ 
    from
        t_student student0_
    where
        student0_.id=1
```

Why is this discrepancy happening?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Hibernate 5.4.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you see described in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query).

> If you are using an entity query that does not contain a `JOIN FETCH` directive Hibernate uses a secondary select.
>
> This is because the entity query fetch policy cannot be overridden, so Hibernate requires a secondary select to ensure that the EAGER association is fetched prior to returning the result to the user.
>
> If you forget to JOIN FETCH all EAGER associations, Hibernate is going to issue a secondary select for each and every one of those which, in turn, can lead to N+1 query issues.
>
> For this reason, you should prefer LAZY associations.

So, you can fix your query in the following way:

```java
entityManager.createQuery(
  "select s from Student s left join fetch s.address where s.id = :id",
   Student.class
)
.setParameter("id", id)
.getSingleResult()
```